# Why this socket is not executed successfully?

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

```
public boolean connection(View view)
    {
        boolean x=true;
        try
        {
            serverSocket= new ServerSocket(9999);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            Toast.makeText(creator.this,"ServerStarted,",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            C.setEnabled(true);

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(creator.this,"Server is not Started,",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
            x=false;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

When this function is going to execute, app stops working.

Why `socket.accept();` is not allowed there?

Comment: The ServerSocket will wait until a a SocketClient connects to it. That's what you intended to?

Comment: Yeah, after successful connection will it work properly? I am getting an error in  **socket=serverSocket.accept();**

Comment: it should work if the other side can opens a socket to your code.

Comment: Post the other side code that try to connect to it, and the error if you have one

Comment: okay I'll post asap

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` as all network code should be executed in a thread or AsyncTask.

When you do then you cannot use a `Toast()`.